# Python's plotly graph does not contain all the values

Tags: python, list, graph, plotly

The following code is supposed to plot a graph using plotly library based on two lists: `ambTime` as X-Axes and `domv1R1Temps` as Y-Axes.
The code is the following:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as ply
from plotly import tools


ambTime = ['10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', 
'10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', 
'10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', 
'10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', '10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', 
'10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', 
'10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', 
'10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', 
'10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', 
'10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', 
'10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', 
'10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', '10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', 
'10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', 
'10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', 
'10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', 
'10:33:23.584', '10:33:23.584', '10:33:23.584', '10:33:23.584', 
.
.
.
.
#This list contains 588 items. I shortened the list for the sake of time
.
.
.
.
'10:35:47.713', '10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', 
'10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', 
'10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', 
'10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', '10:36:08.695', 
'10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.695', 
'10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.695', 
'10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.742', '10:36:08.742', 
'10:36:08.742']

domv1R1Temps = ['27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '28', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27']

Trace1 = go.Scatter(x= ambTime,y = domv1R1Temps, name='DOMV1 R1 
Temperatures')
ambData = [Trace1]
ambLayout = go.Layout(
    title='Ambient Temperature',
    xaxis=dict(
         title='Time',
         ),
     yaxis=dict(
         title='Y Axis'
        )
     )
fig = go.Figure(data=ambData, layout=ambLayout)
ply.plot(fig, filename="Ambient Temperature.html")
```

When I run the code it generates a graph with only 2 variables: Please have a look at the image

[image]

But I want the graph to show every single item from the list. I was wondering if anybody knows what is wrong here?

Comment: I have no idea what values in `domv1R1Temps` correspond to which timestamp, so I don't know how `plotly` is supposed to cope with that either.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a user of plotly, but it seems that it has accepted only the first 21 elements of ambTime as the other list domv1R1Temps has only 21 elements. Because of this the ambTime scale goes till '10:32:53.117' which is the 21st element.

As for why there is no spike shown at temp 28 in the plot, i am not very sure. Maybe something to do with the settings. Ideally you should have a Y entry corresponding to every input X. Tryout with a shorter 21 length ambTime to fix the plot issues first & then find a way to complete rest of entries in domv1R1Temps.

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens when the points are not balanced. I tried the code and made same points on each of them and it worked perfectly fine. This can be a bit tedious for large data files when you miss even one value from any one point the graph won't appear.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as ply
from plotly import tools


ambTime = ['10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', 
'10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', 
'10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', 
'10:32:42.951', '10:32:42.951', '10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', 
'10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', 
'10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', 
'10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', '10:32:53.117', 
'10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', 
'10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', 
'10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', 
'10:33:03.273', '10:33:03.273', '10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', 
'10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', 
'10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', 
'10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', '10:33:13.428', 
'10:33:23.584', '10:33:23.584', '10:33:23.584', '10:33:23.584',
'10:35:47.713', '10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', 
'10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', 
'10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', 
'10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', '10:35:57.884', '10:36:08.695', 
'10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.695', 
'10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.695', 
'10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.695', '10:36:08.742', '10:36:08.742', 
'10:36:08.742']

domv1R1Temps = ['27', '27', '27', '27', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', 
'28', '28', '28', '28', 
'28', '28', '28', '28', 
'28', '27', '27', '27', 
'28', '27', '27', '27', 
'28', '27', '27', '27', 
'28', '27', '27', '27', 
'28', '27', '27', '27', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', 
'27', '27', '27', '27', 
'27']

Trace1 = go.Scatter(x= ambTime,y = domv1R1Temps, name='DOMV1 R1 Temperatures')
ambData = [Trace1]
ambLayout = go.Layout(
    title='Ambient Temperature',
    xaxis=dict(
         title='Time',
         ),
     yaxis=dict(
         title='Y Axis'
        )
     )
fig = go.Figure(data=ambData, layout=ambLayout)
ply.plot(fig, filename="Ambient Temperature.html")
```